# Running any flutter commands says 'Could not install <version>'

Tags: flutter

I am handling different flutter version via fvm. Running 'fvm flutter --version' simply displays

Could not install 2.8.1

Upon running  'fvm flutter --version' , it should return the current flutter version which is not coming to my case. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check .fvm folder under your app root directory and make sure the flutter_sdk pointed correctly. In general all your flutter_sdk will be kept under users directory like in Mac, it will be
/Users/< name >/fvm/version/< specific-version >.

just create a symbolic link of the sdk_version under .fvm should work.

Comment: Can you define what do you meant by
 just create a symbolic link of the sdk_version under .fvm should work.